# MySQL - fine-tuning full-text search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

How can I fine tune MySQL full-text search for my information domain?

For example, I might have a keyword like `js` that I would like the search to recognize, but I don't think allow a minimum word length of 2 be a good idea.

Another scenario I have: I'd like to ignore `3` if that was searched, but would like it to be recognized if the search was `css 3`. Not all single-characters are insignificant, particularly when combined with another string.

Is there a way I can give MySQL a list of words I do not want it to exclude either through it's stop words list or minimum word length variable?

Comment: What is MySQL version(x,y,z)?

Comment: I've requested for my hosting provider to upgrade to the latest version. I'm guessing it'll be 8.x.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is `ENGINE=InnoDB`, here are some tips:

- Set `innodb_ft_min_token_size = 2`; I don't think it is 'bad' idea.  Note:  If you are *changing* this value, do so in the config file, restart MySQL, then rebuild any FT indexes.  (Otherwise, the "2" won't take effect.)
- Programmatically add a `+` in front of each word, and add `IN BOOLEAN MODE`.
- Programmatically:  Either remove 1-character 'words' from the search string, or at least don't add a `+` in front of them.

Here's a trick that is useful sometimes:

```
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('+css 3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND col LIKE '%css 3%'
```

The `MATCH` will happen first (even if it is not first in the `WHERE`).  It will find rows with the word "css", but ignore the "3".  Then the `LIKE` will double check that there is exactly "css 3" somewhere in the string.  Even this is imperfect, since "css 31" will be found.

Comment: Will the stop word still be respected during indexing? How does this successfully find `css 3`?

Comment: @DatabaseNewbie - You may need to specify that there is no stopword list.  (I don't know the details; see the manual.)  And, yes, `AGAINST('+css 3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` will find all rows with the word 'css'.  Alas, it will also find rows with 'css 2'.

Comment: Wouldn't' the `3` be excluded by the indexing? And when a user searches for `css 3`, I want to give more relevance to `css 3` than `css`. Is that what would happen?

Comment: @DatabaseNewbie - No.  The "3" is ignored.  Can't give more relevance _in this example_.  I added some more to my Answer.